# Determine bit depth of bmp file on os x

Tags: macos, image-processing, command-line, imagemagick, bmp

How can I determine the bit depth of a bmp file on Mac OS X? In particular, I want to check if a bmp file is a true 24 bit file, or if it is being saved as a greyscale (i.e. 8 bit) image. I have a black-and-white image which I think I have forced to be 24 bit (using `convert -type TrueColor`), but Imagemagick gives conflicting results:

```
> identify -verbose hiBW24.bmp
...
Type: Grayscale
Base type: Grayscale
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: Gray

> identify -debug coder hiBW24.bmp   
...
Bits per pixel: 24
```

A number of other command-line utilities are no help, it seems:

```
> file hi.bmp 
hi.bmp: data

> exiv2 hiBW24.bmp 
File name       : hiBW24.bmp
File size       : 286338 Bytes
MIME type       : image/x-ms-bmp
Image size      : 200 x 477
hiBW24.bmp: No Exif data found in the file

> mediainfo -f hi.bmp
...[nothing useful]
```

Comment: A nitpick: "greyscale (i.e. 8 bit)" is the wrong way around. BMP supports a 8-bit color-indexed format, but that in itself does not indicate it's grayscale. This is different from PNG, which supports both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a commend-line utility try `sips` (do not forget to read the manpage with `man sips`). Example:

```
*terminal input*
sips -g all /Users/hg/Pictures/2012/03/14/QRCodeA.bmp

*output is:*
/Users/hg/Pictures/2012/03/14/QRCodeA.bmp
pixelWidth: 150
pixelHeight: 143
typeIdentifier: com.microsoft.bmp
format: bmp
formatOptions: default
dpiWidth: 96.000
dpiHeight: 96.000
samplesPerPixel: 3
bitsPerSample: 8
hasAlpha: no
space: RGB
```

I think the result contains the values you are after.

Another way is to open the image with the previewer `preview.app` and the open the info panel.

One of the most informative programs (but not easy to use) is exiftool by Phil Harvey http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ , which also works very well on MacOSX for a lot of file formats but maybe an overkill for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about sips. Unfortunately having had a play it seems to identify 8bpp bmp files as samplesPerPixel=3, bitsPerSample=8, as does the preview.app info panel. BUT exiftool does it right, with Bit Depth: 8 for an 8bpp bmp and Bit Depth: 24 for a 24bpp version. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did this to investigate:

```
# create a black-to-white gradient and save as a BMP, then `identify` it to a file `unlim`
convert -size 256x256 gradient:black-white a.bmp
identify -verbose a.bmp > unlim

# create another black-to-white gradient but force 256 colours, then `identify` to a second file `256`
convert -size 256x256 gradient:black-white -colors 256 a.bmp
identify -verbose a.bmp > 256

# Now look at difference
opendiff unlim 256
```

[image]

And the difference is that the `-colors 256` image has a palette in the header and has a `Class:PseudoClass` whereas the other has `Class:Direct`

Comment: Interesting, although I'm wary of inferring the BPP indirectly like this. Good use of opendiff (which I didn't know about). The easiest solution seems to be exiftool, as recommended in the other answer by Heinrich Giesen.